# Should I use the asset method for my JavaScript files in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, scripting

Im looking for best practice methods in Laravel. I understand that when I have mixing set up for JS in laravel it does wonders. But for individual pages what method is best practice? Any insight would be great!

For example as of right now my scripts look like this

```
<script src="/x/remote/js/js_new/typed.min.js"></script>
```

but would it be more conducive to the Laravel framework by using the asset method like this instead?

```
<script src="{{ asset('/x/remote/js/js_new/typed.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: You need to use `mix(...)` if you are using `mix.version()` (you should be using it). But also, using `asset` or `mix`, you need to point to the public version without using `public` at the beginning of the path

Comment: There is no difference between the two. But lets say you changed your asset folder path (which is highly unlikely) then all you need to do is to copy and paste the existing files into the new folder and Laravel takes care of the rest. With the non-asset approach, you also need to change the relative paths on your scripts as well.